# d3.js update pattern for linked small multiple chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm having trouble creating an update pattern for this below visualisation. It's a linked linechart which is shown for multiple data groups across the page.

Consider data structured like so:

```
data = [
    {
        _id: groupA,
        values: [
            {
                date: 1/1/2016,
                y = 1
            },
            {
                date: 1/1/2016,
                y = 2
            },
            {
                date: 1/1/2016,
                y = 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: groupB,
        values: [
            {
                date: 1/1/2016,
                y = 4
            },
            {
                date: 1/1/2016,
                y = 5
            },
            {
                date: 1/1/2016,
                y = 6
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

And the current pattern, which works find for the initial load:

```
...

var div = d3.select(this)
    .selectAll(".chart")
    .data(data);

div.enter()
    .append("div").attr("class", "chart")
    .append("svg").append("g");

var svg = div.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right )
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom );

var g = svg.select("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var lines = g.append("g");

lines.append("path")
    .attr("class", "area")
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr("d", d => area(d.values))
    .style("fill", d => color(d._id));

lines.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr("d", d => line(d.values));

...
```

If I can get the data join to work on g, it should work fine, but no matter what I try - for example `var g = svg.selectAll("g").data(d => {return {_id: d._id, values: d.values} })`
- nothing works.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1) your question is not clear.
2) can you post a working fiddle

Comment: Yes sure. Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/clery00/shgk5tvc/.

It's just the version used here http://flowingdata.com/2014/10/15/linked-small-multiples/.

Except I'm trying to get this to work when I update the data array, eg. by adding a new `date`, or changing a `y` variable.